# Google Sheets! Trying to figure out linking, comparing, and returning information from a different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my situation. I have one sheet, in that sheet we have multiple tabs that contain different data. On the main tab a Production SKU is put in, the sheet will then populate three product numbers that are needed for that particular SKU. for example:

SKU: US453D1 
This will then go to another tab and vlook what tube, carton, and corrugate is needed and then output  their part numbers in different cells. So this SKU will require tube P9932223 for example.

I have another sheet that keeps up with all tube part numbers that are in stock and the Qty associated with how many production SKU units can be produced with that part.

I want to do this and am not sure exactly the best method to do it.

Lets call the SKU sheet "Sheet A" we will call the tubes inventory "Sheet B"

Attached is a flow chart diagram to better show what I am trying to do. Now one more important thing. I can't just simply add the data from Sheet B to Sheet A and merge them, they are managed by two different departments and that would result in way too much data on one file.

[FlowChartExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeeXv.png)

Comment: Can you please provide a sanitized version of your Spreadsheet to be able to better go over this issue? Also, the best way to do this would be using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview), have you tried any code, formulas or anything to solve this?

Comment: Welcome. You're already accustomed to using "VLOOKUP" to find the carton, tube and case. Why not put another "VLOOKUP" in the "CS Tubes Ahead" cell to get the value from the Tubes Inventory?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I will submit a clean version of both sheets for review a little later today.